# Why does subscribe() not working but aync in template does?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

There is a socket service that sends and receives messages between apps. I can send messages and can also receive those messages in the template with `getMessages | async`. But when I try to replace the `getMessages | async` with a `getMessages().subscribe(...)` in my component it doesn't work anymore. So what I am doing wrong?

Here is the component code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'showTemplate',
    template: `<ng-container #dynamicTemplate>
                    <div class="mx-auto m-5" 
                        [innerHTML]="content" 
                    }">
                </div>

                <!-- WORKS
                    <div *ngFor="let x of showContent() | async">
                        {{ x | json }}--
                    </div>
                -->
            </ng-container>`,
    providers: [ SocketService ]
})
export class ShowTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() data:any;

    constructor(
        private socketService: SocketService,
    ) 
    {}


    ngOnInit() {
        this.socketService.connect();

        // doesn't work
        this.socketService.getMessages().subscribe(response => {
            console.log("------", response)
        })
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     */
    public showContent() {
        return this.socketService.getMessages();
    }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable }                   from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of, Subject }      from 'rxjs';
import { WebSocketSubject }             from 'rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject';

import { environment }                  from '@app/../environments/environment';
import { Message }                      from "../model/message";
import { Status }                       from "../model/status";

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    public serverMessages = new Array<Message>();   
    private socket$: WebSocketSubject<Message>;
    private status: Status;
    private connected: Status;
    private decoderSettings;

    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    ) {
        console.log("SOCKET SERVICE INIT")
        // get logged user
        this.decoderSettings = this.authenticationService.decoderSettings;

        this.connect();     
    }

    public connect(): void {

        const CONTENT_SERVER_URL = 'wss://' + this.decoderSettings.ipAddress + ':9041';

        this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject({
                        url: CONTENT_SERVER_URL,
                        openObserver: {
                            next: value => {
                                console.log("OPEN", value);
                                this.status = Status.CONNECTED;
                            }
                        },
                        closeObserver: {
                            next: value => {
                                console.log("CLOSEING", value);
                                this.status = Status.DISCONNECTING;
                            }
                        }
                    });

        this.socket$
            .subscribe(
                (message) => {
                    console.log('SEND', message);
                    this.serverMessages.push(message);
                },
                (err) => {  
                    this.status = Status.ERROR;
                    console.error(err);
                },
                () => {
                    console.warn('CLOSED!');
                    this.status = Status.DISCONNECTED;
                }
            );
        }

        public disconnect(): void {
            this.socket$.unsubscribe();
        }

        public send(message: Message): void {
            console.log("send: ", message)
            this.socket$.next(message);
        }

        public getMessages():Observable<any> {
            console.log("getMessages: ", this.serverMessages)
            return of(this.serverMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that it is just a simple mistake but I really canot find it after a long search. So thank you for your help!

Comment: define "doesn't work anymore"

Comment: @JamieRees well, I expect to see any new received messages in `this.socketService.getMessages().subscribe(...)`. But nothing is shown here. The code in the template with `<div *ngFor="let x of showContent() | async">` shows me any new messages

Comment: When you subscribe, are you getting the values out of the subscription? e.g. `subscribe(message => this.messages = message);`?

Comment: @JamieRees the inner part of `subscribe()` is called just once. Then is shows me an empty array `console.log(response)`. So the answer is, yes. But it shows just once and any further messages are being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
public getMessages():Observable<any> {
            console.log("getMessages: ", this.serverMessages)
            return of(this.serverMessages);
        }
```

You are creating an Observable which emits the value you pass it (`this.serverMessages`) and then completes. You should create a BehaviourSubject instead of the `serverMessages` array. Then instead of pushing to the Array you should tell the BehaviourSubject to emit a new value. https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Comment: I also tried with `BehaviourSubject` but it doesn't either work

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works because in html you are subscribing anew whenever the view is re-rendered, triggering a new call to getMessages(), creating a new Observable to be returned.

While in code you are subscribing only once, I may be wrong, but it seems like you have the wrong pattern of returning an Observable, since only adding stuff to you array wont trigger an update on the previously returned Observable.

EDIT: If you put a breakpoint in the method getMessages() in the service, how many times do you get a hit? If I'm correct you should get several hits a second if you are focusing on the view.

Answer (score 0):

As expected - my brain is fried. This solved my issue:

```
    public getMessages():Observable<any> {
        return this.socket$;
    }
```